# Asking new question in someone else's topic

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, editing

Is it ok to edit question which is asked by other user to add sub-question?

E.g. Let say I saw post about [hijacking satelite](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/6424/what-would-one-need-to-do-in-order-to-hijack-a-satellite) and I would like to know is it possible to DDoS satelite. Would it be acceptable if I edit that question and add something like

**EDIT by StupidOne**:

Theoretically speaking, is it possible to attack satelitte with DDoS?

In my opinion, openning new question just to ask is DDoS possible while we have this question already asked would be like... Well, spamming.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, you definitely should not add new subquestions by editing an existing question to add things at the bottom. This changes the question and can invalidate current answers.

If you have a followup question, ask a new question, and link to the original question in your followup question, explaining why your new, related question is not addressed by the original question.

These questions will then be linked in the "Linked Posts" sidebar, as well.